# Can't Compress on Android

Tags: java, android, zip

I am trying to compress using zip on Android but its not working. It does create a zip folder of size 3KB but that's it. What i am doing wrong?

```
public static void compress(String infile, String outfile){
    try {
         BufferedInputStream origin = null;
         FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
         ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
         byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
         File f = new File(infile);
         Log.d(TAG, "Only one file found");
         FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
         Log.d(TAG, "File Input Stream available " + fi.available());
         origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
         ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(infile);
         int count;
         out.putNextEntry(entry);
         while((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
               out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
         origin.close();


         out.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

And my calling function is like this

```
String outFile="/sdcard/CPTA/test.zip";
String inFile="/sdcard/CPTA/iso_3166-1_list_en.xml";
ZipUtility.compress(inFile, outFile);
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Are you sure your 3KB output is wrong?  Run `unzip -l /sdcard/CPTA/test.zip` and see if your file is in there.

Comment: i opened it with built in windows zip system and its empty.

Comment: an empty zip file should be much smaller than 3KB.  What else is in that file?

Comment: that's strange basically, when i double click on it, it's open but empty, and when i do right button extract all it generate error message, "windows cannot complete the extraction. The compressed(Zipped) folder 'C:\ADDRESS_OF_MY_ZIPP_FOLDER' is invalid "

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, I'd add closeEntry.

```
     out.putNextEntry(entry);
     while((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
           out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
     origin.close();
     out.closeEntry();
```